Hansel's simple proof of the Skolem Mahler Lech theorem
In his paper 'A simple proof of the Skolem Mahler Lech theorem' Hansel gives a proof of the theorem in the case that the coefficients of the rational series belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. He claims that the case for purely transcendental extensions can be found in Section III and the general case in Section IV - this paper covers only section I and II. Does anyone know where Sections III and IV can be found or how this extension of the proof to these cases can be done?

What you found is essentially a research announcement; publishing these seems to be common practice in computer science.  The full paper was published the next year in Theoretical Computer Science, https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(86)90168-4 (in French).
